# Help with listView and .SelectedItem in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selectedindex

Within my winform(C#) I have listView with two columns, which is used to display the results from searching an array, which is the basic details of an array entry(All data within the array is type string). I am able to add and remove items to the listview, but I would like to be able to gain the value of the row that has been clicked within the listview.

I am planning to use this to update the display full entry info, but I cannot gain the value of the selected item. I was reading elsewhere and saw people mentioning the .SelectedIndex property, but this property is not available to me when I am trying to code.

I could use two listboxes instead of a listview, but the listview is much neater. Also, I am a sofware design (high school) student, and have been learning C# for one and a half years. I am competent at programming, but I start to get lost when things start to get very complex.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

The `ListView.SelectedItems` property works fine if the ListView is not in VirtualData mode.

Comment: Whenever I type out `listView1.selected` the only options that appear in the drop-down context menu (sorry, don't know its proper name. The one that helps complete code) are `SelectedIndexChanged`, `SelectedIndices` and `SelectedItems`. Any ideas?

Comment: SelectedItems is the one to use, is an array since more than one item can be selected at one time.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the SelectedItem property and Tag property

```
var item = (MyClass)  listView1.SelectedItems[0].Tag;
```

tag property allow you to set any type for example MyClass
when you populate the ListView set the Tag property.

Comment: What exactly would the value of the variable `item` be?

Answer (score 0):

For `ListView` check [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could trap the `SelectedIndexChanged` event and in that you could do

```
ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection listItems= 
            this.myListView.SelectedItems;

        foreach ( ListViewItem item in listItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.SubItems[0].Text);
            MessageBox.Show(item.SubItems[1].Text);
        }
```

Comment: If I can't find a way to gain the exact index value, then I can use this to re-search the array and display the searched result, so thankyou. But if I can find a way to get the index value that would be preferable.

Comment: What about the ListView.SelectedIndex?? Can't you get your desired result by the code I provided?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem. After talking to a friend in my software class, he told me to use `listView1.FocusedItem.Index`, which works perfectly for my needs, as it gains the index of the selected item. Also, thank you to everyone for their input in trying to help me.